# e2fsprogs issues on Debian testing - unable to upgrade packages

Tags: debian, upgrade, initramfs, e2fsprogs

After trying to do a regular update on Debian Buster, I ended up with the following issue.

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libraw16
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libraw19
The following packages will be upgraded:
  brave console-setup console-setup-linux e2fslibs glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services inkscape keyboard-configuration libcom-err2 libcomerr2
  libcupsfilters1 libgegl-0.4-0 libgsl23 libgslcblas0 libllvm6.0 liborcus-0.13-0 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libss2 libwpg-0.3-3 libzmq5 logrotate
  skypeforlinux slack-desktop
27 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/262 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,084 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up e2fsprogs (1.44.4-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/e2fsprogs.postinst: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/e2fsprogs.postinst: update-initramfs: not found
dpkg: error processing package e2fsprogs (--configure):
 installed e2fsprogs package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 e2fsprogs
```

apt policy returns the following for `initramfs-tools`

```
initramfs-tools:
  Installed: 0.132
  Candidate: 0.132
  Version table:
 *** 0.132 990
        990 http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.120+deb8u3 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

So, as it seems, I do have `update-initramfs`, but for some reason it won't run. Since I have some jessie backports, the issue may be lying there, but I have no idea what could be the exact problem.

And here is my sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
```

line in your `apt` output presumably refers to `e2fsprogs`, since it doesn’t appear elsewhere (so it has to be pending configuration for its `postinst` to run). This means that the reason `e2fsprogs` won’t configure itself is related to some previous `apt` operation.

To unblock the situation, edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/e2fsprogs.postinst` and change the `update-initramfs -u` line to `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u`, since that’s what’s checked just above. Then run `sudo dpkg --configure --pending`; if that completes successfully, you should be able to use `apt` again without error (at least, without errors related to `e2fsprogs`.

As to the underlying reason, it could be that `/usr/sbin` is no longer on your root path. If that *is* the case, I expect other maintainer scripts will fail...

Comment: Thank you, you're a life savior. And you were also right for the sbin not being on the root path for some reason. With that fixed, everything's working now.

Comment: Thanks it was two other packages from initramfs family that did this and needed to be chenged in the same way.